# Cesium javascript library

Tags: cesiumjs, czml

I want to ask one question about online kml file to czml file converter because i want to convert my kml file into czml file to use it in cesium 3d globe for clickable placemark.Please provide me answer of that question.

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE**: Cesium added official KML support with version 1.7 in March 2015, and the support has steadily improved with additions such as network link support with version 1.27 in November 2016.  See [CHANGES.md](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/master/CHANGES.md) for the complete list.  The answer below references a development branch which was merged and deleted some time ago.

---

Cesium is adding native support for KML so you won't need to convert your KML file to CZML.  It is still a work-in-progress, but it already has more capabilities than the KML to CZML converter.  Using the kml branch in the GitHub repo, drag and drop your KML file onto the Cesium Viewer:

https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/tree/kml

Comment: but how can i drag and drop my kml file in github please provide me help.

Comment: You have to use Git or just click the [Download ZIP](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/archive/kml.zip) button on the KML branch, and build and run Cesium locally.  Then drag-and-drop a KML file on your browser running a local Cesium Viewer.